# How can I pass a specific instance (i.e. not serialized/deserialized) of an object to the new activity I'm starting?

Tags: android, android-activity

Title pretty much says it all.  I need to pass a listener object defined in one activity to the new activity I'm starting.  You can't use serialization for obvious reasons (you'd be notifying the clone, not the original) but I'm not sure how to either send over the object to the new activity, or get the new activity from the old one.

Only solution I've seen so far is to set a static on the new activity, then when the new activity starts up, grab it from the static.  It just feels 'icky' to me, although if you simply set the static, then launch the new activity, you shouldn't run into stateful bugs.

The other is to use local notifications, passing along a notification key, which can be serialized since it's just a key, then set up listeners for it, but that seems to be like driving an 18-wheel semi to the store just to get some milk.

I just keep thinking there has to be a better way. Is there?

Comment: Why not just use a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @tyczj That doesn't send the same instance, it sends a copy.

Comment: @GabeSechan im not suggesting sending the instance I am suggesting using the broadcast receiver to notify like the listener would

Comment: That's what I already mentioned in my question. The difference is, since these only need to be within our own app, to use local notifications.  I think that's the approach we're going to use.  The static just seems to fragile to me.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a singleton or via some injection method like Dagger.  You cannot pass an instance via Intent-  since an Activity could thoeretically be started by any other process, there's no way to pass instances between two activities in the Intent.

Comment: I know you can't do that from the intent.  I'm asking how can one activity get the other activity *started* from that intent.  Is it possible, or no, it's a fire-and-forget kind of thing?

Comment: No, it isn't.  FOr the same reason-  intents are capable of being sent cross-process.  YOu can't send instances cross-process.  Thus only serialized values work.